# How to parse the data in AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, syntax-error

Would like to ask for a help regarding on ajax's success part. I tried to log it on the console but there is this kind of error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number in JSON at position 4
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Function.parseJSON (jquery.min.js:4)
    at Object.success (cta:378)
    at c (jquery.min.js:4)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:4)
    at k (jquery.min.js:6)
    at XMLHttpRequest.r (jquery.min.js:6)
```

Maybe there's something I didn't understand on my code.
Here is my code

```js
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $(".submit").click(function() {    
   var emailval = $("#email").val().trim();
   
   $.ajax({
    url: '/test.php',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: 'email='+emailval,
    success: function(data) { 
     var result = $.parseJSON(data);
     console.log(result);
    }
   });
  });
 });
</script>
```

I wanted to get the value of the email and transfer it to my PHP file. 
Please help

Comment: can you please show your data here?? i think it might be the error in json

Comment: @Joseph its from the form. My form requires email address. So everytime they click on submit button, the jquery and ajax perform.

Comment: no need to use `$.parseJSON()` when `dataType:'json'` is set. `data` will already have been parsed internally. That being said, I don't think your response is valid json either. Copy whole response body from actual request in browser dev tools network and validate  it in jsonlint.com

Comment: @charlietfl oh i see. what variable should I use to get the data log in the console tab then properly transferred to PHP file? can you show example please? thank you so much!

Comment: If the response is valid json just do `console.log(data);`. Always add an error handler to your request also. If it fires inspect it's arguments to understand why

Comment: @charlietfl thanks I didn't received any errors in the console tab now. But my concern is the output is still null. Is there something wrong with the ajax? or in PHP?

Comment: probably php...

Comment: @charlietfl thank you so much for your help! appreciated it a lot!